# Travel from Hahn airport to Bornheim Berger Straße in Frankfurt

Tags: air-travel, hhn

I am flying to Hahn from UK and I  would like to go to Bornheim Berger street in Frankfurt. I just checked the taxis and it is very expensive. I can be picked up or get a taxi once I am a bit closer to Frankfurt. Any idea if there are there any shuttles that are fast and I can share the cost with others?

Comment: Just a small side note: Though the airport is called *Frankfurt* Hahn, it is really far away from Frankfurt, that's why taxis would be horribly expensive. The same goes for *Munich West*, as Memmingen Airport is called by some airlines.

Comment: Yep, This airport naming is a pretty nasty marketing plot. Hahn Airport is not even remotely near Frankfurt and it's actually closer to Luxembourg City than it is to Frankfurt. Fastest would be a rental car. Any form of public transportation will require at least two hours plus whatever waiting is created by the schedule

Answer (score 5):

There is a [bus service that goes from Hahn Frankfurt](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Frankfurt-Hahn+Airport,+55483+Hahn-Flughafen,+Germany/Frankfurt,+Germany/@50.0565722,7.1066237,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47be180426b4755f:0x3db29c6e96461c58!2m2!1d7.2641958!2d49.9458052!1m5!1m1!1s0x47bd096f477096c5:0x422435029b0c600!2m2!1d8.6821267!2d50.1109221!3e3) airport it takes two hours.
You can [buy tickets here](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?S=Hahn%20Flughafen%20Terminal%202&Z=Frankfurt(M)Hbf%20Stuttgarter%20Str.&date=15.10.15&time=14:00&start=1&from_gt=1&dbkanal_004=L01_S01_D001_KPK0054_anreiselink_LZ03).

Then once in Frankfurt like you said you could use taxi.

Comment: I think at least for the Bohr shuttle a direct link here would be better: http://www.bohr.de/linienverkehr/fahrscheinbuchung but you can as well buy the ticket when you arrive there (unless it is during some weird hours)